# how to cast derived BaseModel have isdelete flag in iqueryable, make soft delete repository in entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, casting, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

why this does not work and how I can fix it, I want to make soft delete/hard delete using one repository

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);

    if (query is IQueryable<BaseModel>)
    {
        var baseQuery = query as IQueryable<BaseModel>;
        query = baseQuery.Where(x => !x.isDelete) as IQueryable<TEntity>;
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

this base model class

```cs
public class BaseModel
{
    public bool isDelete { get; set; }
}
```

this the model

```cs
public class Jobs : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Project_Status { get; set; }
}
```

i have this exception

```
{"Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.BaseModel]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Jobs]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Jobs] Where[Jobs](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.Jobs], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Models.Jobs,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0')"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast the `IQueryable<BaseModel>` to `IQueryable<TEntity>` because the `IQueryable<out T>` is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). So you can only cast from IQueryable of more derived types (e.g: `TEntity`) to IQueryable of less derived types (e.g: `BaseModel`).

So here is the solution, you can use `.Cast<T>` to cast the ***element type*** instead of the whole `IQueryable<TEntity>`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);

    if (typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        query = query.Cast<BaseModel>().Where(e => !e.isDelete).Cast<TEntity>();
    }        

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: @AhmedFayez this code has been tested by myself (just for sure). Do you remove your code? keep this code only, don't try to adjust it by your will. If possible, please update your question with ***the exact code*** you tried.

Comment: @AhmedFayez even if this had error, the exception ***could not be the same***. That's simply impossible. Because the casting done here is completely different from yours.

Comment: yes I removed my old code and used your code it is the same exact exception, I think it's the same, no changes in the concept 
- no problem I changed the way that I wrote the code, now I use a global filter, it's better and more secure 
https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/ef-core-in-depth-soft-deleting-data-with-global-query-filters/

Comment: @AhmedFayez please post the exception so that I can help, there must be something wrong on your side because as I said I've tested it on my side.

Comment: @AhmedFayez using global query filters has some trade-offs you need to know about here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#accessing-entity-with-query-filter-using-required-navigation and in some cases, you need to get all the deleted items as well (such as for admin users), so you need to disable the query filter as guided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters

Comment: @AhmedFayez why can't you post the exception?

Comment: @AhmedFayez here's the demo showing that it's working https://dotnetfiddle.net/L9fMsv The way you write the property `isDelete` shows clearly that you're just a newbie in the C# world. So try to love it, want to learn more about it first before you can be better. My answer here has at least 2 things for you to learn. But you focus 100% on the result (based on another approach). That way will never help you be better.